# Visual Studio 2010 linking errors using VTK

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, linker, shared-libraries, vtk

I'm having trouble to compile VTK 5.10.1 example code in Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7 64 bit SP1.

First of all, I installed VTK using [this tutorial](http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~cwyman/classes/common/howto/winVTK.html).
No errors occured while installing VTK and the example executables like cone.exe located at C:\VTK5.10.1_cmake\bin\Release are running just fine.

In Visual Studio 2010 I started a new Win32 console application and tested the first example code from [this site](http://www.vtk.org/VTK/help/examplecode.html).
I edited the projekt properties (additional include directories, additional Library directories and additional dependencies).

The linker errors looked like that:

`vtktest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ""public: void __thiscall vtkRenderer::AddActor(class vtkProp *)" (?AddActor@vtkRenderer@@QAEXPAVvtkProp@@@Z)" referenced in function "_main".`

Most of the the other people with the same error forgot to add the libs to the additional dependencies.
However I added all libs in the C:\VTK5.10.1_bin\lib\vtk-5.10 directory and the opengl32 library. I tried to seperate the libs by a space, a semicolon and a new line.

Then, I read that people are using the shared libraries. I'm not really familiar with dlls. I reinstalled VTK
with shared libraries options turned on and copied the resulting dlls to the System32 directory.
Now, the errors looks slightly different:

`vtktest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ""__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall vtkRenderer::AddActor(class vtkProp *)" (__imp_?AddActor@vtkRenderer@@QAEXPAVvtkProp@@@Z)" referenced in function "_main".`

Any help would be appriciated!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, forgot to change the platform to x64 :/